# Sorting array warning when migrating to .NET 3.5

Tags: vb.net, arrays, .net-3.5

I've just converted my VB.NET application from .NET 1.1 to 3.5, and I'm getting the warning message

> Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type
>   through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.

in

```
Private Function reOrderArray(ByVal arr() As String) As String
   arr.Sort(arr) 'Sort array alphabetically
   'More code...
   return arr
End Function
```

for the words `arr.Sort` on the second line.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Array.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort.aspx) is a static/shared method, and should be invoked appropriately:

```
Array.Sort(arr)
```